# Unresolved local dependency with SBT, Maven, Play 2.0 on Windows

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

I have a first project named Carpooling wich is the domain project. The second Project is a Play 2.0 project named "proto-search"

I have run mvn install for Carpooling and the jar target is at its place in `C:\Users\Java\.m2\repository` along with all other libs.

But when I launch `play run` at the "proto-search" directory, all dependencies are resolved except the Carpooling one. I have :

```
[warn]  module not found: com.s20#biim-model;1.3-SNAPSHOT
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   D:\code\play-2.0.4\framework\..\repository/local/com.s20/biim-model/1.3
-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/s20/biim-model/1.3-SNAPS
HOT/biim-model-1.3-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Snapshots Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/com/s20/biim-model/1.3-SNAP
SHOT/biim-model-1.3-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== OSS Sonatype: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/s20/biim-mode
l/1.3-SNAPSHOT/biim-model-1.3-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== Local Maven Repository: tried
[warn]   file://C:/Users/Java/.m2/repository/com/s20/biim-model/1.3-SNAPSHOT/bii
m-model-1.3-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/s20/biim-model/1.3-SNAPSHOT/biim-mode
l-1.3-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.s20#biim-model;1.3-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] {file:/D:/code/biiim/proto-search/}searchengine/*:update: sbt.ResolveExc
eption: unresolved dependency: com.s20#biim-model;1.3-SNAPSHOT: not found
```

I do have the file at `C:/Users/Java/.m2/repository/com/s20/biim-model/1.3-SNAPSHOT/biim-model-1.3-SNAPSHOT.pom`

My platform is currently Windows. My teammate all use linux and have no problems. Maybe it's the *file://* that doesn't work, but I tried a few workaround with no success.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, I used an unmanaged dependency in the Play Framework. And I quickly moved to Linux and macOS where there was no problem.

Answer (score 3):

try this in your Build.scala:

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

val appName         = "airplane"
val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

val appDependencies = Seq(
    "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.9.2" % "2.0.M4" % "test",
    "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4"
)

// tip from http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.html
resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository"

val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
  testOptions in Test := Nil  // hack to allow us to use scalatest for "play test" rather than specs2    
)
```

}

Comment: Please advise if this worked.  I did not try it with a dependency from my local repo.

Comment: Hi, it didn't work. I use the jar as an unmanaged dependency. I will post on the mailing list of sbt and/or download the sources when I'll have more time.

Answer (score 1):

Add a third forward slash to the resolvers value:

resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file:///"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository"

Answer (score 1):

based on what Todd Flanders answered, It worked for me using only one forward slash in the resolvers part:

resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file:/"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository"